# Avoiding parallel inheritance with service locators

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, dependency-injection

I have the current situation:

A have an abstract class, `Controller`, which has dependencies which are injected at runtime by a service locator, `Locator`. The service locator is properly implemented - it isn't passed all throughout the application, and is consumed only by the `Controller`, which is the root object of the application.

The issue I am having is how to structure the service locator(s) when I inherit from `Controller` - I don't necessarily want (and would prefer not to) to extend the base service locator `Locator`, but I need to duplicate the dependencies of the parent class.

Here's some sample code to explain what is going on:

```
// Controller.php
namespace abstract;

abstract class Controller {
    public function __construct( $locator ) {
        $this->template_handler = $locator->getTemplateHandler();
        $this->input_sanitizer = $locator->getInputSanitizer();
    }
}
```

-

```
// Controller.php
class Controller extends abstract\Controller {
    public function __construct( $locator ) {
        $this->data_factory = $locator->getDataFactory();

        parent::__construct( $locator );
    }
}
```

-

```
// Locator.php
namespace abstract; 

class Locator {
    public function getTemplateHandler() {
        return 1234;
    }

    public function getInputSanitizer() {
        return 1234;
    }
}
```

So I guess the question becomes - how to I define my `Locator` class? Do I extend `abstract\Locator` (creating a parallel inheritance tree), do I implement the same methods without extending `abstract\Locator` (this duplicating code), or do I do something different that I haven't thought of?

Comment: `namespace abstract;` is not valid syntax

Comment: That's very true. I also forgot my requires, and `Controller` has no other methods than the constructor. Thanks for the insightful tip.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one Locator in all controllers. Unless services are very specific, of course. Otherwise what would be the purpose of a service locator if you had to locate the required locator first?